# Apache Ignite Cluster Formation fails during Kubernetes Blue Green Deployment

Tags: java, kubernetes, ignite, blue-green-deployment

I am deploying kubernetes pod through blue green deployment. The POD is a micro-service which uses Ignite in embedded mode and forms a cluster when deployed hence data is shared among the service instances. Things were working fine during rolling deployment.

However during Blue Green Deployment using harness a new services is created for green deployment as well as the deployment Objects and Pods are created. During this time the configuration of Ignite Still points to the original service (blue service) this is done as later in blue green deployment services are switched. However once the services are switched Ignite fails to form a cluster and data is not shared among the instances.

Configuration used to form Cluster

k8sConnectionConfiguration -> object is crated by setting namespace and Service Name
TcpDiscoverySpi is created using TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder

```
KubernetesConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new KubernetesConnectionConfiguration(); 
connConfig.setNamespace("namespace");
connConfig.setServiceName("service-name");
TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder tcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder = new TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder(connConfig);
TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
spi.setIpFinder(tcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder);
igniteConfig.setDiscoverySpi(spi);
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that before services were switched all nodes from blue and green deployments were in the same cluster since the blue service was used for all of them in the discovery configuration? What error do you get in the logs after the switching?

Comment: Yes they are in same cluster. I tried using Green Service as well but same result. 
There are no errors in the log just ignite data is not shared and Topology Snapshot in Logs shows server=1
The Blue deployment (V1) does not have Ignite . The Green Deployment (V2) we are introducing Ignite. 

If the V2 deployment is rolling one , then one by one V2 Instances comes up and forms a cluster. However in Case of Blue Green deployment where all Instances of V2 PODs comes up almost at same time , they are not able to form cluster. Is Multicast is supported in Ignite Kubernetes Deployment ?

Comment: Why do you need to create a new service during an update? Are you re-creating one of the deployments completely or what?